# Google charts table chart array

Tags: arrays, google-visualization

I'm using google charts with this code:

```
    <?php

function testing($chartId, $chartFunc, $chartTitle, $xAxisTitle, $chartData, $chartType)
{
$pageMeat =<<<EOD
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback($chartFunc);
function $chartFunc() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable($chartData);

var options = {
title: '$chartTitle',
hAxis: {title: '$xAxisTitle', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
};
EOD;

if($chartType == "line") {
$pageMeat .=<<<EOD
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('$chartId'));
EOD;
}
else if($chartType == "pie") {
$pageMeat .=<<<EOD
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('$chartId'));
EOD;
}
else {
$pageMeat .=<<<EOD
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('$chartId'));
EOD;
}
$pageMeat .=<<<EOD
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="$chartId" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
EOD;
echo $pageMeat;
}

$gChartId = "vertColumns";
$gChartFn = "columnChart";
$gChartTitle = "Company Performance";
$gXAxisTitle = "Year";

$gChartData[] = array('Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses');
$gChartData[] = array('2004', 1000, 400);
$gChartData[] = array('2005', 1170, 460);
$gChartData[] = array('2006', 660, 1120);
$gChartData[] = array('2007', 1030, 540);

testing($gChartId, $gChartFn, $gChartTitle, $gXAxisTitle, json_encode($gChartData), "column");
?>
```

It works with line, pie and columncharts but when i try to use a table chart https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table
It doesn't seem to work, how can i use a array with this table chart?
Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

you need to include the table package...

```
packages:["corechart", "table"]  // <-- include table package here
```